# Custom comparator for custom class, just like STL

Tags: c++, stl, comparator

I have a custom class Binary search Tree. I want to pass a comparator class as an argument (with default being std::less). Most of the answers I searched use the STL objects and then pass their custom comparators. I want something different.

// Tree class

```
template <class T,class Compare = less<T>>
class Tree
{
    struct TreeNode
    {
        T data;
        struct TreeNode *  left;
        struct TreeNode *  right;
    };
public:
    void insert(T);
};
```

// Custom comparator class

```
template <class T>
class CustomCompare
{
public:
    bool compare(const T&, const T &);
};


template<class T>
bool CustomCompare<T>::compare(const T & a, const T &b)
{
    cout << "calling custom comparator";
    return a<b;
}
```

// inserting in tree

```
template<class T,class Compare>
void Tree<T,Compare>::insert(T val)
{
      // HOW DO I CALL COMPARE HERE? I tried this
      if (compare(val->data , treeNode->data))  /// does not work.
       // I get error - use of undeclared identifier compare.


      //IF I DO THIS, I get error - expected unqualified id
       Compare<T> x; // cannot create instance of Compare

      // IF I DO THIS< I can create instance of Compare but cannot call function compare.
       Compare x;

       x.compare(....) -- Error no member named compare in std::less


}
```

I cannot make the `CustomCompare::compare` static as I want the code to work for std::less too.

I hope the question is clear.

Note: I know I can overload `operator <` for the classes that will be using it. I am preparing for the situation in case source code of those classes is not available

Comment: You have to create an instance of `Compare`.

Comment: If I do that, I get error: No member named compare in std::less<int>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::less` has the following function to compare objects.

```
bool operator()( const T& lhs, const T& rhs ) const;
```

If you want to use a custom compare class to be an equal substitute, you have to have such a function in that class too.

Then, you would use it as:

```
  if (compare()(val->data , treeNode->data))
```